# When published django-cms plugin from edit mode html template doesn't render model objects. But content reappears when switched to edit mode

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Actually, I am new to Django-cms world. I tried almost every duplicate of this same question but none of them worked. I have created my custom plugin with just one ManyToManyField().

I went through Django-docs For many-to-many or foreign key relations to other objects but that didn't helped. Maybe I am lost somewhere, I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

## Try1 PluginModel :

```
class PortfolioPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    portfolio = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio)
```

## Try2 PluginModel :

```
class PortfolioPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    portfolio = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        for p in oldinstance.portfolio.all():
            p.pk = None
            p.plugin = self
            p.save()
```

## Try3 PluginModel :

```
class PortfolioPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    portfolio = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio)

    def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
        self.portfolios = oldinstance.portfolios.all()
```

Apps Model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='portfolioImage',blank = True, null = True)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

cms_plugins.py

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin  # register the plugin
class PortfolioPluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    model = PortfolioPluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    # model = Portfolio(CMSPlugin)
    module = _("Portfolio")
    name = _("Portfolio Plugin")  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "portfolio_cms_integration/portfolio_plugin.html"
    cache = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context
```

portfolio_plugin.html

```
<div class="filters-content">
            <div class="row grid">
                {% for p in instance.portfolio.all %}
                <div class="single-portfolio col-sm-4 all vector">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <div class="overlay overlay-bg"></div>
                            <img class="image img-fluid" src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="" style="width:399px; height: 400px;">
                        </div>
                        <a href="{{ p.image.url }}" class="img-pop-up">
                            <div class="middle">
                                <div class="text align-self-center d-flex"><img src="{% static 'img/preview.png' %}"
                                        alt=""></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="p-inner">
                        <h4>{{ p.author }}</h4>
                        <div class="cat">{{ p.description }}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Expected output : `When I publish my post I should see my model objects of portfolio app`
Actual output: `When I publish my post I dont see any model objects of portfolio app`

Comment: What file is "Apps Model:"

Answer (score 0):

Your last try works perfectly, you just need to delete the plugin and add it again. It should make use of the copy_relations function this time. You should then see your plugin inside the published view.

Don't forget copy_relations if you have ForeignKeys or ManyToManyField inside your CMSPlugin model.
Fore more information checkout Django CMS documentation about [handling relations](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.6.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html#handling-relations).